# Encode image to WebP

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I convert some images to WebP? I want to select some images from device and send it to backend (or just save to disk) in WebP format, but I can't find any solutions for this problem.

I've found `image` plugin but it don't support encoding to WebP, only to PNG, JPEG and several other formats.

Comment: I've written my own plugin: flutter_webp

Comment: i cant find it.

Comment: ok i just did thanks for this

Comment: does it support animated webp file resizing and conversion from gif to animated webp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library: [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

This library can convert images to `Webp` format.

It is a famous & feature-rich library for these types of needs.